# Sandisk Extreme Portable SSD (1TB) not visible

Tags: macos, ssd, external-hard-drive, nas

I have a SanDisk Extreme Portable SSD (1TB), and have been using it for two years without any issue.

This weekend I connected it to a new Synology NAS (DS223) and tried to copy the files over. The Synology NAS detected this SSD is in the ExFAT format and asked me to install the driver/package. I followed the instruction to install the driver/package, restart the NAS. However, the SSD still didn't show in the NAS.

I unplugged the SSD and plugged it to my MacBook Pro. It appears that the SSD didn't show on my Mac machine either. I tried to mount the SSD again with the Disk Utility, but didn't see the SanDisk SSD over there. I ran the System Information, and found that the SSD was connected under the USB tab (Please see screenshot).

I tried to run the SanDisk Security and see if I could get the SSD back. Unfortunately, the SanDisk Security could detect the SSD, but it reported that there is no volume (Please see screenshot).

I tried to connect the SSD on a Windows machine. The Disk Manager could detect the SSD, but it reported that there is zero byte in the SSD.

Does anyone have a solution? I have tons of family images and videos in the SSD and I really want them back.

Mac System Information:
[image]

Sandisk Security:
[image]

Comment: It's very likely the drive failed and best thing would be contacting a data recovery specialist at this point.

Comment: And stop using it until you have a way to recover the data -- each time it is plugged in or unplugged, it increases chance of data loss.